# overflow-y:scroll in bxSlider (horizontal slider) Part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As a newbie, I realized too late that it is not possible to add code in comments.
So I opened a new question and asking again for your help.

For reasons of space I'm using bxSlider with fixed width and height (width 500px + height 300px). All images have the same width, but some of the images have a greater height than 300px.

As I mentioned - for reasons of space - I don't want to use `adaptiveHeight`, but (vertical) `overflow:auto`, but the result is always unsatisfactory, because now a scrollbar appears at each image - in the length of the image with the greatest height.

I just want to have a vertical scrollbar, when the height of an image is more than 300px.

Is this possible?

I tried this in **query.bxslider.js**:

```
.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;  
    padding: 0;  
    *zoom: 1;  
    width:500px;  
    height:300px;  
    overflow:auto;  
}

.bx-wrapper img {  
    max-width: 100%;  
    display: block; 
}
```

Because my query knowledge is still low, I also tried to use `overflow:auto` in the 
.bx-wrapper img, but it didn't work, too.

Comment: try `overflow-y:auto` but without an example it's hard to say

Comment: You can edit your own question to add code, Just click "edit" below your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use javascript. And if you're so inclined, you can adapt this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/wj93t/) for your purposes.

Just click on the radio buttons to see different sized pictures.

JS

```
$('input:radio[name=photoradio]').change(function(){
    pnum = $('input:radio[name=photoradio]:checked').val();
   changethepicture(pnum);
});


function changethepicture(pnum)
{
  var photonum = $('.photo img:nth-child('+ pnum +')');
  $('.putmehere').html( photonum.height() );

  if( photonum.height() > 350 )
    {
      $('img').css('display', 'none');
      photonum.css('display', 'block');
        $('.photo').css('height', '350px');
      $('.photo').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
     }
      else
    {
     $('img').css('display', 'none');
     photonum.css('display', 'block');
     $('.photo').css('height', 'auto');
     $('.photo').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
     }
}
```